# Tail -f with pagination

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, unix, shell

I am trying to tail file with pagination

`tail -f foo.txt | more`

This works fine until file gets lets say 200 lines injected, when this happens nature of `tail` command is to go to end of file, at that point I lose track of trailing the log. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Use `less` instead of `more`.

Comment: Decided to double down? http://askubuntu.com/questions/210960/paginate-with-tail-f-command

Comment: @Snesticle Yes I'm desperate, is it against the rules?

Comment: Are you reading from a pipe? If so your option "-f" gets ignored.

Comment: I suggest [`multitail`](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/) as an alternative to plain `tail`. You can buffer any number of lines and scroll back on the buffered lines.

Comment: @Dolphin: [cross-posting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/186615) is frowned upon.

Comment: It works with piping to Less for me, otherwise the answer below seems likely.

Comment: @Snesticle Actually works quite nice, just like mentioned tail -f will just jump to end file after you have came to end of file with more.

Comment: @Dolphin http://ss64.com/bash/tail.html

Comment: As Snesticle has already mentioned, in the future, please don't cross post. Choose a site where you like to ask on, and if you don't get an answer, you can have the question migrated. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `less` with `+F` instead of `tail/more`:

```
less +F foo.txt
```

When you want to take a look around, hit <kbd>Ctrl-c</kbd>. To restart following (tailing), hit <kbd>F</kbd>.

Comment: Not exactly what I had in mind but works nicely. Thank you +1 from me and if nothing closer to target accept from me.